# Change initial icon's color in Navigation Drawer

Tags: android, colors, navigation-drawer, android-theme, android-icons

I downloaded a sample of Navigation Drawer and the icons are initially black. When they are loaded to the menu, they get pink and I can't find anywhere in the code where it has been changed  to pink.

Menu loaded: The text is right but the icon...

[image]

Navigation drawer code:

```
 <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main2"
        app:menu="@menu/activity_main2_drawer"
        android:theme="@style/MyNavigationDrawer"/>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

activity_main2_drawer code:

[image]

Navigation Drawer theme:

```
<style name="MyNavigationDrawer" parent="AppTheme">
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorAccent</item>
        <item name="android:icon">@color/colorAccent2</item>
        <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/colorAccent2</item>
    </style>
```

Apptheme:

[image]

Comment: Did you check you java code. If some code is there to change icon color.

Answer (score 0):

Check there is not any code like this.

```
navigationView.setItemTextColor(ColorStateList1);
navigationView.setItemIconTintList(ColorStateList2);
```

One can change icon color using this.

```
int[][] states = new int[][] {
        new int[] {-android.R.attr.state_enabled}, // disabled
        new int[] {android.R.attr.state_enabled}, // enabled
        new int[] {-android.R.attr.state_checked}, // unchecked
        new int[] { android.R.attr.state_pressed}  // pressed

};

    int[] colors = new int[] {
            Color.WHITE,
            Color.BLUE,
            Color.WHITE,
            Color.WHITE
    };

    ColorStateList ColorStateList2 = new ColorStateList(states, colors);
```

You should not have this as per your reqirement.

Comment: there is no code like this in the code. I looked carefully. It's so weird... Nor the color is in the color.xml.

Comment: I also added your code and nothing changed... weeeidd.. In spite of this,  thank you very much.

Comment: What happens when you implement it in new project ?

Answer (score 0):

Use app:itemIconTint="your desire color" in

```
<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
            android:id="@+id/nav_view"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="start"
            app:itemIconTint="your desire color"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main2"
            app:menu="@menu/activity_main2_drawer"
            android:theme="@style/MyNavigationDrawer"/>
```

Avoid using 
 @color/colorAccent2
 @color/colorAccent2
in style.